# Why the State value doesn't reset after View init

Tags: swiftui

In my testing code:

```
import SwiftUI
struct A: View {
    @State var i: Int
    let a: Int
    init(a: Int) {
        self.a = a
        _i = State(wrappedValue: 2)
        print("init a=\(a) i=\(i)")
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("a=\(a)")
            Text("i=\(i)")
            Button(action: {i += 1}, label: {Text("i+=1")})
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var a: Int = 22
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            A(a: a)
            Button(action: {a += 1}, label: {Text("a+=1")})
        }
    }
}
```

When I press button `[a+=1]`, I can see the print `init a=23 i=2`. But the value `i` in view is not reset to 2. Why `i` always increases at view?

Comment: Because SwiftUI manages your @State variables for you and keep them alive even if the view is re-created. As I understand it the lifetime of `i` is tied to the lifetime of the `ContentView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `State` property is joined to specific view type in specific location and updated when rendering engine interprets that view is *the same*. The is a base of SwiftUI rendering optimisation - it redraws bodies only of those views which internal state is changed and does not if view remains the same.

So if you need the entire view would be reconstructed, you have to explicitly give it uniqueness, eg. with providing `id`, like

```
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            A(a: a).id(a)       // << here !!
        ...
    }
```